# foreign key problem in mysql

Tags: mysql

hay i have two tables i want to relate them with a foreign key i made it locally and works fine using innoDB but when i upload it to my server database the type of table automatically change to myISAM. when i checked the type again i found that there is no innoDB engine type instead MyISAM, MEMORY, BLACKHOLE, EXAMPLE, ARCHIVE, CSV,FEDERATED, MRG_MYISAM were there. please help which storage engine out of these can support foreign key.

Answer (score 3):

None of them. Only innodb supports FKs.

Comment: but no innodb was there now what should i do any kind of help please

Comment: @hunter: you have nothing to do now, because **only** innodb supports foreign keys.

Comment: show engines; command will let you know if InnoDB is disabled. And the error log will let you know why was it disabled.